# Using frame parameter to making a plot from ggplot to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Here is my data:

```
data <- data.table(year = rep(1980:1985,each = 5),
                   Relationship = rep(c(" Acquaintance","Unknown","Wife","Stranger","Girlfriend","Friend"),  5),
                   N = sample(1:100, 30)
                   )
```

I can use plotly::plot_ly function to plot a Dynamic map of the years like this:

```
plot_ly(data
        ,x=~Relationship
        ,y=~N
        ,frame=~year
        ,type = 'bar'
)
```

[image]

but when I using ggplot with parameter `frame` ,I get a error 
`Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator`

here is my ggplot code :

```
p <- ggplot(data = data,aes(x =Relationship,y = N ))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(frame = year))
ggplotly(p)
```

Can you modify my ggplot code to produce the same graph ？

This example runs successfully using frame parameter:

```
data(gapminder, package = "gapminder")
gg <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = year)) +
  scale_x_log10()
ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: I get `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: frame`. What it's supposed to do?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen This `frame` parameter  is for plotly ,not in ggplot2.

Comment: That's a bug I think. I have just opened an issue on Github to report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case others are still looking, this does appear to be a bug related to `geom_bar`. Per Stéphane Laurent's GitHub report (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1544) a workaround is to use `geom_col(position = "dodge2")` or `geom_col(position = "identity")` instead of `geom_bar(stat='identity')`